# What types of files does ExpiresDefault include?

Tags: htaccess, apache, cache, cache-control, expires

I have:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 years"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 months"
```

As you see, there are some rules for images and `ExpiresDefault` for the rest. But, what are the file types that `ExpiresDefault` will work on ? Are php files also included here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, what are the file types that ExpiresDefault will work on ?

As you've stated, "the rest". Any responses that are not covered by the mime-types stated in the preceding `ExpiresByType` directives are covered by the `ExpiresDefault` directive.

So, from the directives you posted, this will include HTML (`text/html`), JS (`application/javascript`), CSS (`text/css`) and anything else you are serving.

> Are php files also included here ?

Well, that depends what mime-type your PHP files are being served with.

Ordinarily, your PHP files probably default to a `text/html` mime-type since you often serve HTML content from PHP files (by default). In which case, your `ExpiresDefault` directive will include these responses, since `text/html` is not covered by the specific `ExpiresByType` directives.

However, PHP can potentially serve anything. Your PHP file could generate a JPEG image, in which case it *should* be served with a `image/jpeg` mime-type (in the `Content-Type` HTTP response header). In this case, the `ExpiresByType image/jpeg ...` directive will cover this response and `ExpiresDefault` will *not* apply.

*Aside:*

> ```
> ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 months"
> ```

The `plus` keyword is entirely optional. It is just syntactic sugar, to make it more readable.

So, include it or not - it is up to you. But, as with everything, it is important to be consistent. Include it OR don't include it; don't mix.

> ```
> ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 years"
> ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
> ```

You don't need both of these. Your server is (or "should be") responding with only one or the other mime-type for JPEG images. It "should be" `image/jpeg`, which is the official mime-type. However, you could have a "buggy" script that thinks otherwise.

Check the `Content-Type` HTTP response header for the mime-type that is being served. That is the only one you *need* to target.